# PDO connect error on xampp for windows

Tags: php, pdo, xampp

I'm new to PDO and am trying to use it on xampp for windows. I keep getting an error relating to the host and have tried changing 'localhost' to everything possible such as ip address and sockets but i believe i'm not doing it right. I've also tried changing the variable for pdo_mysql.default_socket but I don't believe that it's working/I'm doing that right either.This is the error I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' to database ''xxxxxx''' in C:\xampp\htdocs\faculty\classes\db.class.php

This is what i currently have in my php

```
self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname='xxxxxx'", 'admin', 'xxxxxxx');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove single quotes around dbname as in

```
self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxxx", 'admin', 'xxxxxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an account for `admin@localhost` in mysql? PDO's connecting just fine, but you're using incorrect credentials to log into the database.

Specific docs on creating accounts: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: I tested it with a regular mysql_connect connection and everything worked out for both mysql_connect and mysql_db_select using the same settings as the PDO connect so it's not the login

Comment: mysql_connect doesn't specify a database, so that will succeed even if the account being used has no rights on the database. ensure that you've granted this admin user rights on your xxxxxx database.

Comment: i've connected with both the mysql_connect AND mysql_db_select and both were successful. The account has no global permissions only for that database. Is there any other non-PDO way to test this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and turns out my xampp mysql database had two "any" entries that were generating a warning in the users page of phpmyadmin that I was ignoring.

I managed to connect with PDO once I removed those two entries... go figure.

To sum up: remove the "any" users from your php users list, if they are there.